# HTC VIVE SteamVR how to render different content in each eye

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm have a scene with **3 cameras** `CameraRig`, `CamLeft` and `CamRight`.

Now I would like to be able to switch between two modes.

**Mode 1:** `CameraRig` renders to both HTC vive headset eyes (`CamLeft` and `CamRight` are disable).

**Mode 2:** `CamLeft` renders to the left eye and `CamRight` renders to the right eye of the headset (`CameraRig` is disable).

I have searched for a solutions and found some answers Like [d**iscussion on steam community**](https://steamcommunity.com/app/250820/discussions/0/535152276589455019/) and a [**gameDev Post**](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/152451/rendering-2-different-images-in-hmd-for-left-and-right-eye-using-streamvr) but no luck.

Comment: Please mention the problem

Comment: I can't display two normal unity camera on the htc vive headset. One camera for the left eye and one camera for the right eye.